# Putting a base model extended class in the application/models folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a `base_model extends CI_Model` class and put it in `application/model`. Then, I created another class that extends `base_model`, but I get the following error:

> Cannot find this class

Other resources told me to put the `base_model` in:

```
application/core
```

or:

```
application/libraries
```

However, I would like to put it in `application/models` for convenience. Can I put this class in `application/models` and still have it work correctly?

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to use the [naming convention for model classes in CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy), mainly, `Base_model`, not `base_model`. Note the initial capitalized character.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a MY_Model class in your application/core folder instead.  First-level inheritance was built into CI by default, i.e.:

**{APPATH}/core/MY_Model.php:**

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

In that same file, if you want alternate parent classes, try:

```
...
class Base_model extends MY_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
...
```

If you don't put it in MY_Model, YOU ARE RESPONSIBLE for loading the base model first (before an extended class references it), AND you can't have a file in your models/ folder called Base_model.php, for example.

Comment: Thank you! If you know about the ionize cms, it can put the base_model in the application/models and do not put any My_Model elsewhere! I do not know how they can do that! I try the autoload file but do not see where they put the autoload for the model!